# Set environmental variable on Vagrant guest OS automatically?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm guessing this is very simple, but I've been looking everywhere:

I want to be able to set an environmental variable on my guest OS whenever I bring up a Vagrant box. I don't want to run only on provisioning, because then every time my box is halted it would need to be re-provisioned.

This seems like it should be an incredibly easy thing to do, perhaps just something basic in the Vagrantfile, but everything I've tried has failed.

Is this possible without plugins (or with)?

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 possibilities:

1. if you do not want to run any provisioning, you will need to make it in the guest OS once and then repackage the VM as a new box so when you'll start new VM from this new box, they will always and automatically have all settings defined before you did package as new box
2. run a provisioning, still, its not so bad idea. For example something like

   ```
   $script = <<SCRIPT
   echo "alias lt='ls -lt'" >> .bashrc
   echo "export NEW_ENV_VAR=...." >> .bashrc
   SCRIPT

   Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

     blablabla
     config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script, privileged: "false", run: "always"

   end
   ```

This will set few variables inside `.bashrc` file (you can set in `.profile` if you prefer)

`run: "always"` makes sure this provisioning is run everytime you do up or reload (might not really be needed once the variables are in place)

`privileged: "false"` will make sure it is run with your vagrant user, so it will update in vagrant .bashrc file, if you do not specify this option, makes sure to reference the full path of the file `.home/vagrant/.bashrc` otherwise it will be done for root user